# Setting up PerformanceCounter with PropertyGrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, propertygrid, performancecounter

I'd like to create a `PerformanceCounter` on the fly by setting up its arguments with a `PropertyGrid`. If I set `PropertyGrid.SelectedObject` to the `PerformanceCounter` its not providing the same options as in the IDE.
[image]

How can I do the trick? Is it possible at all?

Comment: The properties added in the Properties window are specific to the designer.  Like GenerateMember, you won't generate members in your PropertyGrid.  Very unclear why you think that's a problem.

Comment: I don't think its a problem. I'd like to archive the same thing as I see in designer and would like to know how.

Comment: Sorry I meant *achieve

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is some PerformanceCounter properties such as CategoryName are marked with the [ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.readonlyattribute.aspx) attribute. When the property grid sees a ReadOnly attribute on a property, you can't edit it, so you can' have the drop down with the list of category names.

I don't know how what magic the designer uses to overcome this, but here is my solution. We add a custom [TypeDescriptionProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider.aspx) to the instance of PerformanceCounter edited, and provide a custom type descriptor that removes the ReadOnly limitation.

This is how you can use it (with a propertyGrid1 instance of the PropertyGrid class):

```
PerformanceCounter counter = new PerformanceCounter();

// use a custom type description provider for this counter
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new PerformanceCounterTypeProvider(), counter);

// filter unwanted properties
propertyGrid1.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute.Visible);

// select it in the property grid
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = counter;
```

And this is the utility code used:

```
public class PerformanceCounterTypeProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private static PropertyDescriptor[] _properties;

    static PerformanceCounterTypeProvider()
    {
        List < PropertyDescriptor> properties = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(PerformanceCounter)))
        {
            PerformanceCounterPropertyDescriptor clone = new PerformanceCounterPropertyDescriptor(pd);
            properties.Add(clone);
        }
        _properties = properties.ToArray();
    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        return new PerformanceCounterTypeDescriptor();
    }

    private class PerformanceCounterTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
    {
        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(PerformanceCounterTypeProvider._properties.ToArray());
        }
    }

    private class PerformanceCounterPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        private PropertyDescriptor _desc;

        public PerformanceCounterPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor desc)
            : base(desc, new List<Attribute>(desc.Attributes.OfType<Attribute>()).ToArray())
        {
            _desc = desc;
        }

        public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            // we can't use _desc.SetValue because the underlying property descriptor checks it's read only
            ComponentType.GetProperty(Name).SetValue(component, value, null);
        }

        public override bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
        {
            return _desc.CanResetValue(component);
        }

        public override Type ComponentType
        {
            get { return _desc.ComponentType; }
        }

        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            return _desc.GetValue(component);
        }

        public override Type PropertyType
        {
            get { return _desc.PropertyType; }
        }

        public override void ResetValue(object component)
        {
            _desc.ResetValue(component);
        }

        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
        {
            return _desc.ShouldSerializeValue(component);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked it and the `GetValue` routine throws that category name is missing. Could you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9cyd296%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) there are some settings that can't be changed during runtime.  This would indicate to me that, by default, the propertygrid will only show those settings that can be changed during runtime and there will always be a difference between what settings you see in designtime and what settings you see in runtime.

Comment: I'd like to change the `CatergoryName`, `CounterName`, `InstanceName`, `MachineName`. These could be changed during runtime. I only wanted to know is there a general solution (ex.: a setup class or structure) for setting up a `PerformanceCounter` with a `PropertyGrid`